Nominalism and Epistemology
What would you say are the impacts of nominalism on one’s epistemology? I know that there are different strands of nominalism and we could probably nuance ourselves in to obscurity, however, I'm looking for a rough sketch of how a nominalistic position will impact ones epistemology.
